# Error in Facebook application in IE

Tags: facebook

In my Facebook application one page is giving this error in IE but it is working in Mozilla. Please help me.

```
Message: FB is undefined
Line: 154
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http:------
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the FB javascript object is not loaded yet or cannot be loaded.

Make sure to wait for the document to be ready before calling FB.init()!